# calling a dynamic function in javascript

Tags: javascript

is it possible to call a dynamic method in javascript. ie suppose i have in my page 2 methods as such:

```
function id1_add()
{
  return 1;
}

function id2_add()
{
  return 2;
}
```

i also have this function:

```
function add()
{
  var s1='id1';

  s1+'_add()'; //???
}
```

is it possible to call for example id1_add() in such:

```
 s1+'_add()';
```

so the method call depends on a previous string?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Aside from Tim's method you can also `eval(s1+'_add()');`.

However this method can be unsafe if not used correctly.

See [When is JavaScript's eval() not evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil)

A better option would be to have a function to which you pass a different parameter depending on what you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

In the specific case of function declared in the global scope **only**, you can do

```
window[s1 + "_add"]();
```

Note this will not work for nested functions. This also relies on the global object being mapped to `window`, which is the case in all scriptable browsers.

Comment: +1 less awful than `eval`. But in any case, it's a code smell. An explicit lookup of names to functions might be preferable.

Comment: Yep. I lazily omitted the "are you sure you should be doing this?" bit.

Comment: @bobince: `eval` is not necessarily awful. It really depends on how you use it (see discussion in my answer).